# Bundle item tab loads empty section

Tags: magento-1.9

I have upgraded magento 1.9 to latest magento 1.9.4.0 . In admin on product edit, when i click on the bundle item it loads a empty section but actually its has item. And when i click on add item,nothing happen but gives a console error "bOption is not defined". i am also attaching the image so that you can all have a clear idea
[image]